# Is there a way to fix lagging when scrolling a large canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to implement a parallax scrolling effect with vanilla JS/HTML/CSS; what I've implemented already works, but there seems to be a lag with the undermost background canvas (I've made three canvases, one to hold the player/other obstacles, one to hold a background, and one to hold a foreground). The lagging seems to be only happening with the background (not the foreground).

```
// Drawing the background
  draw() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    // Preventing browser(s) from smoothing out/blurring lines
    this.ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    this.ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    this.ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    this.ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

    this.ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.posX, 0, this.image.width, this.image.height, 0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    this.ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.posX - this.image.width, 0, this.image.width, this.image.height, 0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    if (this.image.width > this.canvas.width) {
      this.ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x - this.image.width * 2, 0);
    }

    if (this.posX >= this.image.width) {
      this.posX = 0;
    }

    this.scrollImage();
  }

  // Scrolls an image
  scrollImage() {
    this.posX += this.speed;
  }
```

I've tried using whole numbers for the `speed` to avoid calculating decimal pixel sizes and after looking at some other posts with this problem, it seems like workarounds are difficult to find. (Actually, I'm not quite sure if this is exactly my problem, but that's the only reason for the lag that I can think of). It is strange that the foreground is scrolling seamlessly though.

Here's everything that you'll need to reproduce the problem (I won't post the entire code files since it'll be too long, but I'm sure people can gather the remaining boiler plate form of the files):

// index.html

```
<body>

  <canvas id="background-canvas"></canvas>

  <canvas id="foreground-canvas" height="302" width="802"></canvas>

  <div class="overlay-wrapper"></div>

  <canvas id="game-canvas" tabindex="1"></canvas>

  <p>Press tab to play</p>
</body>
```

// index.js

```
const Game = require('./game');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // Getting main game canvas
  const gameCanvas = document.getElementById('game-canvas');
  const gameCanvasCtx = gameCanvas.getContext('2d');

  // Parallax scrolling effect
  // Getting background canvas
  const backgroundCanvas = document.getElementById('background-canvas');
  const backgroundCanvasCtx = backgroundCanvas.getContext('2d');

  // Getting foreground canvas
  const foregroundCanvas = document.getElementById('foreground-canvas');
  const foregroundCanvasCtx = foregroundCanvas.getContext('2d');

  const game = new Game(
    gameCanvasCtx,
    gameCanvas,
    backgroundCanvasCtx,
    backgroundCanvas,
    foregroundCanvasCtx,
    foregroundCanvas
  );

  game.start();
});
```

// game.js

```
class Game {
  // Constructor for game
  constructor(gameCtx, gameCanvas, backgroundCtx, backgroundCanvas, foregroundCtx, foregroundCanvas) {
    // Setting context and canvas
    this.gameCtx = gameCtx;
    this.gameCanvas = gameCanvas;
    this.backgroundCtx = backgroundCtx;
    this.backgroundCanvas = backgroundCanvas;
    this.foregroundCtx = foregroundCtx;
    this.foregroundCanvas = foregroundCanvas;

    // Setting game state
    this.gameOver = false;
    this.paused = false;

    // Binding class methods
    this.draw = this.draw.bind(this);

    // Creating background and foreground
    this.createBackground(this.backgroundCtx, this.backgroundCanvas, this.foregroundCtx, this.foregroundCanvas);
  }

  // Creating the background and foreground
  createBackground(backgroundCtx, backgroundCanvas, foregroundCtx, foregroundCanvas) {
    // Background
    const backgroundImage = new Image();
    backgroundImage.src = '../dist/assets/images/background.png';
    backgroundImage.alt = 'Background';
    this.background = new Background(backgroundCtx, backgroundCanvas, backgroundImage, 1);

    // Foreground
    const foregroundImage = new Image();
    foregroundImage.src = '../dist/assets/images/foreground.png';
    this.foreground = new Background(foregroundCtx, foregroundCanvas, foregroundImage, 10);
  }

  // Drawing the game
  draw() {   
    if (!this.gameOver) {
      requestAnimationFrame(this.draw);
      // Drawing background
      this.background.draw();
      this.foreground.draw();
    }
  }

  // temp start function for game
  start() {
    this.draw();
  }
}
```

// background.js

```
class Background {
  // Constructor for background
  constructor(ctx, canvas, image, speed) {    
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.image = image;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.posX = 0;
  }

  // Drawing the background
  draw() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    // Preventing browser(s) from smoothing out/blurring lines
    this.ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    this.ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    this.ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    this.ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

    this.ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.posX, 0, this.image.width, this.image.height, 0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    this.ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.posX - this.image.width, 0, this.image.width, this.image.height, 0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    if (this.image.width > this.canvas.width) {
      this.ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x - this.image.width * 2, 0);
    }

    if (this.posX >= this.image.width) {
      this.posX = 0;
    }

    this.scrollImage();
  }

  // Scrolls an image
  scrollImage() {
    this.posX += this.speed;
  }
}
```

And in my css file, this is how I styled my canvases:

```
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* For rendering sprites without blurring */
canvas {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

/* Canvas styling */
#game-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  tabindex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

#background-canvas {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

#foreground-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Sure, I'll sort out the essential code snippets!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "lag"? Also since it's vanilla js, you should be able to create a working snippet for us to try.

Comment: Like, the background scrolls over a few pixels, then it stays while the duplicate background begins to scroll over (so at first the a square looks like a normal square, then it scrolls and the square becomes a rectangle, then it scrolls again, and it becomes a square again) Kind of like a growing/shrinking motion of the image while it moves across the screen.

Comment: Hm, I've never made a working snippet, but let me see if i can whip something up

Comment: Don’t work with multiple canvases for starters. Work with a single canvas and work on layering and blending your images over each other on a single canvas. That will immediately give you a massive performance boost over clearing multiple contexts before each draw.

Comment: If you don't want to squeeze everything into a snippet here, you can do something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jsqwmu (This is a draft project I made using your code, but it's unfinished)

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for the suggestions! @Diniden, would you happen to have a good guide on how to layer images on top of one canvas??

Comment: Also, I saw that in some other posts similar to this, people were saying that having multiple canvases for the background/foreground, and main game were better for performance; is this wrong??

Comment: You 'can' theoretically get better performance using multiple canvas only if you were to make it so that you could reduce the amount of redraws, but you'd be hard pressed to make it actually work and would have to operate within a lot of constraints and specifics to browser optimizations. I'd suggest you work on getting a single canvas working first, then you can focus on 'odd' optimizations later. It'd be easier for you to understand the 'whys' for something working better.